# jquery pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am using some images as pagination markers. I am appending them to a span like so.

```
for(var i=0;i<25;i++){
     if(i==0){
        $('#page').append("<img  src='images/on.gif'/>");
        }
     $('#page').append("<img  src='images/off.gif'/>");
 }
```

Now when I click my next or previous buttons I first need to set them all to off? Then set the specific one say 5 to on?

How can I change them to the correct images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget for loops, this can be done with jQuery selectors. Put these two lines in the proper place in your javascript file.

```
$('#page img[src*="on.gif"]').attr('src','images/off.gif'); // selects all images whose src contains "on.gif" and sets all to off.gif

$('#page img:eq(5)').attr('src','images/on.gif'); // set just the 5th one to on.gif
```

Does this work?

Comment: The :eq selector is very cool (+1) but note the caveat from the docs: "Because `:eq()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:eq()` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index)` instead.

Comment: Interesting addendum, thanks for the tip on using .eq(index)!

Answer (score 1):

yes, exactly as you said, why didn't you try it before asking?
By the way, here's problem with your syntax

```js
for(var i=0;i<25;i++){
```

it shouldn't be

```
for(var i=0;i<25s;i++){
```

EDIT

```
$("img").click(function(){
      $("img").attr('src', 'images/off.gif');
      $(this).attr('src', 'images/on.gif');
});
```

Comment: That was at typo. I got them them there. I need to know how to turn the right one on now. If I was on page 5 how do I turn the 5th one on and the rest off.

Comment: use property :eg(5) after img selector

Answer (score 0):

I would do: (assuming you have nothing else in `"#page"`

```
var page = $('#page');
for(var i=0;i<25;i++)
{
   page.append("<img src='images/off.gif' />"); //Sets them all to off.
}

$("#page img")
    .click(function(){
        $("#page img").attr("src", "images/off.gif");
        $(this).attr("src", "images/on.gif");
    }) //event handler to set this one to on.
    .first().attr("src", "images/on.gif"); // Sets the first one on by default
```

If you have otherthings inside `"#page"` just give the images a class and be more specific in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentpage = 0;

$("#next").click() {
    previouspage = currentpage;
    currentpage = previouspage + 1;
    $('#page'+currentpage).append("<img  src='images/on.gif'/>");
    $('#page'+previouspage).append("<img  src='images/off.gif'/>");
}

$("#back").click() {
    previouspage = currentpage;
    currentpage = previouspage - 1;
    $('#page'+currentpage).append("<img  src='images/on.gif'/>");
    $('#page'+previouspage).append("<img  src='images/off.gif'/>");
}
```

Assuming the span you are appending to has an id of "page0", "page1" etc and your next and back buttons have an id of "next" and "back".